# Pdf file uploaded using JMeter but the content is missing in that pdf file means file gets corrupted

Tags: pdf, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I need to upload a pdf file through backend API using JMeter. So for that, I passed a multipart API request. To upload the file I am using BeanShell Preprocessor.

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\XYZ\\Downloads\\PT_003.pdf");
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
for (int i; (i = in.read(buffer)) != -1; ) {
 bos.write(buffer, 0, i);
}
in.close();
byte[] binarydata = bos.toByteArray();
bos.close();
vars.put("binarydata", new String(binarydata));
```

Multipart Request Body :

```
--AaC07x
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8


{
  "token":"a6b8J000000055JQPU",
  "flow":"Development"
}
--AaC07x
content-disposition: form-data; name="File"; filename="PT_003.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Transfer-Encoding: bytecode

${binarydata}
--AaC07x--
```

Header Manager:-

```
Content-Type    multipart/related;boundary="AaC07x"
```

File uploaded but content in that pdf file is missing means when I tried to open the uploaded pdf file it's blank/corrupted.

So can you please anyone help me to fix that issue??

Answer (score 0):

1. It looks like your byte array to string conversion is the problem. Moreover as per [JMeter 5.5](https://lists.apache.org/thread/k575c2oqnr0pv52fckcg399o4nkqt8c6) you cannot simply send a byte array using [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler as given you put everything into "Body Data" tab it will be treated as a [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)
2. [Since JMeter 3.1 you should avoid using Beanshell](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting), the recommended scripting language is [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)
3. If you have problems coming up with a proper request definition you can just record it using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html), just make sure that your `PT_003.pdf` is in JMeter's "bin" folder during both recording and replay